# Formulate an equation to find a fixed point

Tags: programming, core-language

I have the following equation: `Subscript[x, n + 1] = Subscript[x, n]^2 + c` with `Subscript[x, 0] = 0`. This equation is restricted to the reals and `c` is real.

How do I input this into *Mathematica* to find the fixed point?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Maybe start with [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html).

Comment: `Solve[(a^2 + c) == ((a^2 + c)^2 + c), a, Reals]` and then some thinking

Comment: Or `Reduce[(a^2 + c) == ((a^2 + c)^2 + c), a, Reals]`

Comment: @belisarius - it is sufficient to use `Solve[x == x^2 + c, x, Reals]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Of course. I was trying to be on the pedagogy side. Probably made the thing more confusing instead of clearer. Oh, well

Answer (score 3):

The comments so far give you an answer where the fixed point is, and what condition to the variable c must hold. If I understand you right you want simply to key this in Mathematica to find a fixed point (for given c). 
There are various ways. Here is one of them. First define a function to search the fixed point for:

```
fun[x_, c_] := x^2 + c
```

Then you can calculate a fixed point by (initial guess 0.2):

```
FixedPoint[fun[#, 0.2] &, 0.3]
```

(* 0.276393 *)

btw, you can see the evolution to the fp with NestList:

```
NestList[fun[#, 0.2] &, 0.2, 5]
```

(* {0.2, 0.24, 0.2576, 0.266358, 0.270946, 0.273412} *)

Now you can also easily visualize the fixed points (for a given c)

```
data = Range[0, 0.24, 0.01];fp = FixedPoint[fun[#, data] &, 0.1]
```

and

```
ListPlot[{data, fp}\[Transpose]]
```

[image: Fixed Point between 0 an 0.24]

Comment: `1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 c]`

Comment: @belisarius: Sure, exactly ;-)